# Making list with specific name

Tags: lisp

Hi
how can I make a list with specific name , for example making this list with name myList = ( 1 2 3 4 5 ).
thanks

Answer (score 6):

Globally:

```
(defvar my-list (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

Locally:

```
(let ((my-list (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
  <code using my-list goes here>)
```

**Note:** There are no lexical global variables in ANSI Common Lisp (though one can fake them using `define-symbol-macro`).  Declaring a global variable with `defvar` or `defparameter` makes the variable `special`, thus removing lexical properties like closure from the variable.  Because of this, you may want to distinguish special from lexical variables by using earmuffs in the variable's name:

```
(defvar *my-list* (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```